# Presenting UIViewController with clear background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, temenos-quantum

I'm writing iOS FFI methods for Kony application. In that, I'm presenting a viewcontroller with clear backgroundcolor. But, it's showing a white background view. I'm not using storyboars, I'm designing views in code only. In the newviewcontroller viewdidload, I set the self.view background color to clearcolor.

Here's what I have tried,

```
NewViewController *newVC = [[NewViewController alloc]init];
newVC.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
newVC.definesPresentationContext = YES;
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[KonyUIContext onCurrentFormControllerPresentModalViewController:newVC animated:YES];
```

I'm new to KonyUIContext, how can I fix this?

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: @BhavinRamani, no, I'm designing view in code only. in the newviewcontroller viewdidload, I set the self.view background color to clearcolor

Comment: Ok. Then please edit your question with above comment.

Comment: @BhavinRamani, Edited...

Comment: try newVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;

Comment: @Saraswati, instead of self.modalPresentationStyle, setting newVC.modalPresentationStyle to UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext does the trick. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code... It works perfectly for me....

```
MyViewController *modalViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;           
[KonyUIContext presentViewController:modalViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I'm using KonyUIContext...,

Comment: instead of self.modalPresentationStyle, setting newVC.modalPresentationStyle to UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext does the trick

Answer (score 0):

try this , You just need to set backgroundcolor to clear color of your viewcontroller's view .

```
NewViewController *newVC = [[NewViewController alloc]init];
newVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
newVC.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
newVC.definesPresentationContext = YES;
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[KonyUIContext onCurrentFormControllerPresentModalViewController:newVC animated:YES];
```

Hope this Helps!